# How can I convert a timing function from linear to cubic Bézier?

Tags: math, animation, timing

I have an animation sequence that shows one specific frame after another. The original specifications were:

- We will give you a total duration for the animation
- Reduce the time each consecutive frame is shown by 20ms

So I wrote this linear timing function:

```
/**
 * Get the delay until the next animation frame.
 *
 * @returns the number of ms until the next animation frame.
 */
getNextTiming: function () {
    var n = this.getLength(), // total number of frames
        t = this.animationDuration,
        x = this.durationDelta, // 20 ms, according to spec
        d = ((n * n * x) - (n * x) + (2 * t)) / (2 * n),
        c = this.cursor; // current frame
    // d is the duration of the first frame of animation.
    return d - c * x;
},
```

Naturally, the artists aren't happy. They want the animation to follow a curve. Of course, they don't know exactly what curve, so I need to write something I can tweak numerically until they're happy. It seems to me I should be looking at cubic Bézier functions, but the ones that I can find either have abstract notation that I'm finding difficult to parse, or they're defined as p(t), instead of Δt/Δp.

I used to be good at math, but right now I'm stuck. I could use a shove in the right direction. How can I rewrite the above function so that I can feed it cubic Bézier control points P1 and P2 and get as output the time for each consecutive frame?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific what you want? A Bezier curve is a function over the domain [0,1]. But you're asking for a list of timings, which is a function over the domain {0, 1, 2, ...}.

Comment: @RaymondChen Hmm… that's a good point. What if we redefine the above so that n=1 and t=1, and allow the rest of the values to be fractional? Then to get *real world* values I would just multiply the output by the total animation duration in ms. Would that be sufficient to normalize it?

Comment: If you need to reduce each frame duration by a fixed amount, that is a linear function. No matter what "curve" you model, the results will be linear. `Duration[n] = InitialDuration - 20 * n`

Comment: @belisarius true. We need to throw out the fixed duration delta.

Comment: @kojiro So, what replacement to use?

Comment: @belisarius I was hoping that the Bézier control points would be sufficient to describe the curve, once we throw away the fixed Δt.

Comment: @kojiro It's impossible to guess about that. You should gather the requirement from the user. What do they expect?

Comment: @belisarius The control points would be variables set as properties of the parent object. They would be fixed at runtime, but they need to be easy to tweak.

Comment: @kojiro http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/notes/splines.pdf

Comment: @belisarius Thanks, I've now read through that document twice. I still don't quite understand what the P1 and P2 control points tell me, mathematically. Should I be able to derive the slope and curvature at P0 and P3 from those points?

Comment: @kojiro You may understand it better by playing around a little with http://www.sunsite.ubc.ca/LivingMathematics/V001N01/UBCExamples/Bezier/bezier.html

Comment: I wonder about a similar topic. Both SVG and CSS can represent complex curves with Bezier. So the defined input is Bezier. Nothing I can do about it if I don’t want to spend my time influencing the standardisation committees. But I might want to represent curves in other math formats using SVG and CSS. Therefore, I wonder how I can translate other models to Bezier, without losing precision.